# type arguments [T] do not conform to method product's type parameter bounds [T <: Product]

Tags: scala, apache-spark, generics

I want to use this code to read csv file. but it cause an generics error. why? I think I was specified type like "".

```
def readMoviesData[T](spark: SparkSession, dataPath: String): Dataset[T] = {
  import spark.implicits._
  spark.read.format("csv").schema(Encoders.product[T].schema)
    .option("header","true").load(dataPath).as[T]
}

def analysisMovies(dataPath: String): Unit = {
  val spark = SparkSession.builder().appName("analysis movies data").getOrCreate()
  val movies: Dataset[MovieModel] = readMoviesData(spark, dataPath + "/movies.csv")
  movies.createOrReplaceTempView("movies")
  spark.sql("select count(*) from movies")
}
```

error

```
Error:(10, 53) type arguments [T] do not conform to method product's type parameter bounds [T <: Product]
spark.read.format("csv").schema(Encoders.product[T].schema)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

try to add `Product : TypeTag` in T bounds and use implicit encoder for `T`:

```
import scala.reflect.runtime.universe.TypeTag
def readMoviesData[T <: Product : TypeTag](spark: SparkSession, dataPath: String): Dataset[T] = {
  implicit val encoder: Encoder[T] = Encoders.product[T]
  spark.read.format("csv").schema(encoder.schema)
    .option("header","true").load(dataPath).as[T]
}
```

Answer (score 4):

The error message says:

`product` expects its type parameter to be a subtype of `Product`, but your type parameter is unrestricted, and thus could be anything, including something that is not a subtype of `Product`.

So, one way of solving it would be to make sure that you restrict `T` to be a subtype of `Product`.

Comment: but I use it like this, it is all right.                                                                                             
val ratingsOrigin = spark.read.format("csv").schema(Encoders.product[RatingModel].schema)
      .option("header","true").load(dataPath + "/ratings.csv").as[RatingModel]

Comment: Then `RatingModel` is probably a subtype of `Product`.

Comment: RatingModel it is a case class.  case class RatingModel(userId: Int, movieId: Int, rating: Double, timestamp: Timestamp)

Comment: Case classes automatically inherit from `ProductN` (i.e. `Product4[Int, Int, Double, Timestamp]` in your case), which in turn inherits from `Product`.